# converting vector form of text to numpy : array is too big

Tags: python, numpy, nltk

I am trying to cluster text documents using gaac in nltk .The code is as below .

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.cluster import GAAClusterer
from gensim import corpora
import numpy
import gensim
import itertools


filepath='C:\ISSS609\Forum'
corpus=PlaintextCorpusReader(filepath,'.*')
fids=corpus.fileids()
docs=[corpus.words(f) for f in fids]
dictionary=corpora.Dictionary(docs)
vec=[dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]
vec2=list(itertools.chain(*vec))
vectors = [numpy.array(f) for f in vec2]
clusterer = GAAClusterer()
clusterer.cluster(vectors,False)
clusterer.dendrogram()
```

below is the error that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aditya/PycharmProjects/untitled1/test2.py", line 21, in <module>
    clusterer.cluster(vectors,False)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\gaac.py", line 41, in cluster
    return VectorSpaceClusterer.cluster(self, vectors, assign_clusters, trace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py", line 57, in cluster
    self.cluster_vectorspace(vectors, trace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\gaac.py", line 52, in cluster_vectorspace
    dist = numpy.ones(dims, dtype=numpy.float)*numpy.inf
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 178, in ones
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Kindly suggest a work around .

Comment: Well, how big is the array and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: it is the vector for arond 560 one liner text files. (565 kb) ( this is just a sample) the main data set will be a lot bigger  (about 10 mb ) .

I have about 8 gb of ram

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what your trying to do. It looks like you create a bag of words representation for each document, then join all the bag of words vectors into one vector, and then assign each element of the new vector to an array?

Comment: yes, is this the right approach ? , because the gaac.clusterer does not accept a bag of words vector as input

Comment: what does it accept as an input?

Comment: it expects a single list of vectors

Comment: followed this example http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~matuszek/fall2013/clusterdemocode.py